# Add React Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I know this is probably a simple question but dont know where to go. I have a site that lets a user make a request and a dashboard that shows all of the requests. What Im trying to do is to add just a simple infinite scroll so not all the requests load right away. I just want the basic once you scroll down a little it will load more of the requests.

This is what my dashboard looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import requiresLogin from './requires-login';
import LinkButton from './LinkButton';
import { fetchRecs } from '../actions/recommendations';
import { POSTER_PATH_BASE_URL } from '../config';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import './dashboard.css';

export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
componentDidMount()
{
    this.props.dispatch(fetchRecs());
}

render() {
    let recs;
    if (this.props.recs) {
        recs = this.props.recs.map((rec, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} className="card">
              <section className="dash-recommended">
                <section className="dash-movie-poster">
                  <Link to={`/movie/${rec.movieId}`}><img
                    src={POSTER_PATH_BASE_URL + rec.posterUrl}
                    alt="movie poster"
                  />
                  </Link>
                </section>
                <section className="dash-container">
                <section className="dash-rec-user">
                <h3><Link to={`/user/${rec.userId.id}`}>{rec.userId.username}</Link></h3></section>
                <section className="dash-movie-title">
                <h3><Link to={`/movie/${rec.movieId}`}>{rec.title}</Link></h3></section>
                <section className="dash-recommend-desc">
                  <p>{rec.recDesc}</p>
                </section>
                </section>
              </section>
            </li>
          );
        });
      }

    return (
      <section className="dashboard-container">
        <section className="myRecommended">

        <section className="recommended-list">
        <section className="profileButton">
            <LinkButton to='/profile' className='profileBtn'>My Recomendations</LinkButton>
            </section>
            <section className="recommendButton">
        <LinkButton to='/recommend' className='recBtn'>+ Recommend</LinkButton>
        </section>
          <section className="recommendation-header">
            <h2>Recent Activity:</h2>
          </section>
          <ul className="recent-activity">{recs}</ul>
        </section>
        </section>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the infinite scroll plugin I was looking to use
https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component

This is what the github shows on the documents

```
<InfiniteScroll
 dataLength={items.length} //This is important field to render the next data
 next={fetchData}
 hasMore={true}
 loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
 endMessage={
<p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
  <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
</p>
}
// below props only if you need pull down functionality
refreshFunction={this.refresh}
pullDownToRefresh
pullDownToRefreshContent={
<h3 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>&#8595; Pull down to refresh</h3>
}
releaseToRefreshContent={
<h3 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>&#8593; Release to refresh</h3>
}>
{items}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

So really Im just looking for like a push in the right direction on where to start with the how to grab the length for my "recs" and what to do with the "next" part. Of if anyone has a simpler way for adding infinite scroll Im all ears.

So Im told I need to do some refactoring. Im kind of lost on what I need to refactor on this to make this work.

Comment: The `length` is the `recs.length` and `next` is your `fetchRecs` refactored as an instance method which will fetch the next recs and append them to the currently available ones. This component seems to rely on the localstate of his parent (because of the `next` props) so as you seem to be using redux (which uses global state) you may need to refactor your code a little bit.

Comment: Ya Im using Redux. So refactoring my code will be the best way to go? Or do you know of a solution for infinite scroll for Redux?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629773/infinite-scroll-react-redux